# Standard incidence rate

Tags: meta-analysis, incidence-rate-ratio

I am conducting a meta-analysis where I pool standard incidence ratio's. Several of the studies do not give the SIR between the groups I would like to compare but do give the SIR relative to another group.

Example:
Group A (exposed to factor A) vs general population: SIR 5.6 (CI 3-8)
Group B (exposed to factor B) vs general population: SIR 8.9 (CI 7-14)

I know the amount of patients in group A and B, but I do not know the mean follow-up of each group.

Is it possible to obtain the SIR and their confidence interval between Group A and B from the given information? And how which analysis should I use?

Comment: I also know to amount of events in each group.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but perhaps this technique could be used: https://www.medcalc.org/calc/comparison_of_means.php . Because SIR is usually (I think) calculated with Poisson regression, perhaps the figures need to be logartihmised first, and the result then exponentiated. I'm not sure if this is a valid method. Also, the groups need to be (both the exposed groups and the general populations) must of course be comparable.